# How do I separate datamapper observer class into a different file from the model class?

Tags: ruby, model, datamapper, observer-pattern

I'm running into an error when I try to split the dm-observer class into a separate file from my model class. Previously it worked fine if I put it all into a single file.

```
# test_observer.rb
require 'dm-observer'

class TestObserver
  include DataMapper::Observer
  observe Test 

  before :create do
      # does funky stuff
  end 
end 

# test.rb  
require 'dm-core'
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/test_observer'

class Test
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial
  property :name, String
  property :state, Integer
end
```

Every time I require the Test class, I run into the error:

```
uninitialized constant TestObserver::Test (NameError)
```

I'm not sure why the TestObserver:: is prepended to the class name. I have a feeling I'm not putting the requires in the right places, but I've tried everything and it still won't play nice. Would appreciate any help on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You require test.rb which requires test_observer *before* Test class is declared. You should remove this line:

`require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/test_observer'`

and require files in that order:

require 'test'

require 'test_observer'

Comment: Thanks again solnic! that worked great. Is there any way I can work the require for test_observer into test.rb so that I do not have to worry about requiring the observer class every time I use the Test class?